# how to unpacks and rebuild rpm package on fedora?

Tags: linux, fedora, rpm

how to unpacks and rebuild rpm package on fedora?
Could any one help me on this!

Comment: what is your purpose to repack RPM ?

Comment: i'm try to edit dependency RPM package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the src.rpm: use

```
rpmbuild --rebuild the.src.rpm
```

If you don't have the source, and also no way of getting it: you can extract a RPM using rpm2cpio, and similarly pack it back together.

Comment: how to use rpm2cpio on fedora?
when i extract a RPM with this command how to use spec file